# Diffie Hellman: Why is $(\mathbb{Z}_{8191}^*, \times)$ an insecure group?

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman

I noticed that all the binary bits of $8191$ are $1$'s. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Maybe it has more with the fact that 8191 is tiny...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides 8191 being too small for real world use, the factorization of 8190 ($p-1$) has all small values. It's factorization is $2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5 \cdot 7\cdot 13$. Having a group whose order is [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) makes it vulnerable to an attack using the [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm).